# Extract colon delimited fields/values from text file with awk/sed/cut/grep

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, split

I would like to extract from a text file some delimited field/values that come in pairs, they might appear in any position in a line or paragraph. The file might contain several long or short paragraphs. I want the output either as one only row per file or row per occurrence. I have performed several options where I have managed to obtain the first occurrence of a fieldname or the second one but not both of them. I can get the N fieldname in one "pass" and then I need to run a second one for the following fieldname with order related issues.
Any suggestions to get this done in one line command?

```
Text File 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus orci justo, quis faucibus arcu scelerisque molestie. 
Curabitur :Field1 Value1: lacus at scelerisque :Field2 Value2: aliquam. Aenean mattis elit et magna volutpat, eu finibus justo cursus. 
Etiam non cursus nisi. Donec urna nulla, convallis ut velit sit amet, accumsan faucibus urna. :Field1 Value2: lacinia lectus :Field3 Value2: bibendum ligula dictum gravida. Duis eget metus sed lorem scelerisque varius. 

Text File 2
Duis leo sem, placerat eget :Field3 Value1: volutpat eget, condimentum at odio. Ut iaculis tincidunt massa, in :Field1 Value2: accumsan nulla bibendum quis. Sed tincidunt justo sit amet est bibendum mollis. Fusce gravida nunc a nibh blandit ullamcorper. Aliquam auctor laoreet pellentesque :Field1 Value1:
Quisque tempor ultrices congue.
Mauris feugiat est sed neque malesuada tincidunt. Pellentesque fringilla, nunc vitae porta tempor, mauris felis ultricies eros, ac hendrerit lacus odio et nisi. Vivamus cursus lacinia nunc, a mollis mi hendrerit a. Nunc commodo dui nec iaculis fringilla.

Desired output for Text File 1

FieldName1 Value2 FieldName2 Value2  FieldName1 Value1  FieldName3 Value2

FieldName1 Value2   
FieldName2 Value2
FieldName1 Value1
FieldName3 Value2

Desired output for Text File 2

FieldName3 Value1  FieldName1 Value2  FieldName1 Value1

FieldName3 Value1
FieldName1 Value2
FieldName1 Value1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! what have you tried so far? Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

If you take colon as the field separator, you'll find that your placeholders are the *even*-numbered fields:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' file
```

will get you most of the way there.